# Method's execution time in java

Tags: java, performance, spring

I want to print the execution time for a method in java. Currently am using the following code,

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
// method body
long runTime= System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
System.out.println(" XYZ Method execution time: " + runTime);
```

There are so many methods for which I would like to find the runtime in the project, is there any way to prevent writing this piece of code in every method?

The project uses Spring 2.5, Struts 2.

Edit:I do not want to add the logic to every method, I would like to, say, write the logic once and use some kind of configuration where I can specify the methods for which I need to print the execution time. So whenever the method is executed, automatically the run time should get printed to the console. One way is as said by me is to add the code to prologue and epilogue, but I do not want to edit the method as that would be time consuming and writing the same code wont be a good practice.

Comment: if you want performance logs  use perf4j @ http://perf4j.codehaus.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just use a profiler, like [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/) or [JVisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html). JVisualVM comes with the JDK.  If you really want to do this yourself, use `java.lang.instrument` and `ASM` to write your own agent.  It's simple to add logic to the prologue and epilogue of a Java method using this approach.

Here's a link to get you [started](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19309.html).

Comment: Can you please add a sample?

Comment: Added a link to help demonstrate

Comment: How to get method's execution time in java by VisualVM?

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you take a look at the [Metrics](http://metrics.codahale.com/) package from Codahale. This package collects various metrics (including timing) which is then reported via JMX or other mechanisms.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1 :: Use AOP

Option 2 :: If you are logging at the right places (before & after), and are throwing in the time stamp in your logs, you could just use any analytics tools (logrythm, splunk's open source version, etc.) to just crunch your logs and figure out the times. However keep in mind logging is generally an expensive operation (well, so is AOP to some extent).

Whichever approach you take, make sure to count for the performance impact you are going to put on your application just to measure performance itself :-).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Spring AOP, you can use around advice to calculate method execution time

[Spring 2.5](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.5/reference/aop.html)

[Spring 3.0 x](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html)